# Como usar variáveis declaradas em outras páginas JSP após o include?

Tags: java, jsp

Tenho uma página jsp com apenas dois includes no código todo:

```
<%@ include file = "../_global/prefixos.jsp" %>    
<%@ include file = "../_global/testaProfessor.jsp" %>
```

Em `prefixos.jsp` tenho o seguinte:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c"    uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Em `testaProfessor.jsp` tenho o seguinte:

```
<jsp:useBean id="validaLogin" class="dao.usuario.TestaLoginUsuario" />

<c:set scope="request" var="usuarioLogado" value="${validaLogin.testaLoginUsuario(pageContext.request)}" />
```

O  `<c:set scope="request"` da página `testaProfessor.jsp` não tem acesso ao `<%@ taglib prefix="c"` da página `prefixos.jsp`

O que devo fazer para resolver esse problema?

---

#### EDIÇÃO

a resposta dada pelo @Bruno César, embora possa ajudar em outras situações, no contexto do meu problema não ajuda.

O caso é que se eu incluir um arquivo a dentro de um b, o que esta em a pode ser usado em b. Mas não é isso que eu preciso.

Preciso é que em dois arquivo a e b sejam incluídos em um arquivo c e que o conteúdo do arquivo a esteja disponível ao arquivo b também. Não apenas ao arquivo c.

Alguma ideia?

Exemplo:

arquivo index.jsp

```
<%@ include file = "../_global/prefixos.jsp" %> 
<%@ include file = "../_global/testaProfessor.jsp" %>
```

Preciso que o conteúdo de `prefixos.jsp` fique disponível para `testaProfessor.jsp`

preixos.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c"    uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

testaProfessor.jsp

```
<jsp:useBean id="validaLogin" class="dao.usuario.TestaLoginUsuario" />

<c:set scope="request" var="usuarioLogado" value="${validaLogin.testaLoginUsuario(pageContext.request)}" />
```

Comment: Como você está declarando a variável?

Comment: Adicionei dados ao final da pergunta @Bruno César

Comment: Você quer é aproveitar a declaração da taglib, é isso?

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi... você pode incluir a variável no escopo de requisição, por exemplo: `request.setAttribute("foo", "valorDeFoo");`.

Comment: @re22 então, foi o que entendi inicialmente. Depois de atualizar a resposta já mudou, parece que ele quer reaproveitar a declaração da taglib. De toda forma vou atualizar uma resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer o reaproveitamento de declarações de *taglibs* você deve você deve usar a diretiva *include*, algo assim:

```xml
<%@ include file="<nomeDoArquivo.ext>" %>
```

Esta diretiva faz a inclusão estática, sendo avaliada em tempo de tradução da página, ou seja, quando o JSP ainda não foi compilado.

O `<jsp:include />` é dinâmico e é utilizada mais para dados dinâmicos vindos de outras páginas JSP.

Como boa prática você pode separar todas as *taglibs* em um arquivo `taglibs.jsp`, por exemplo, com um conteúdo próximo a este:

```xml
<%@ taglib prefix="c"    uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn"   uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

Nas outras páginas, basta fazer a inclusão deste arquivo, sempre antes do primeiro uso, algo assim:

```xml
<%@ include file="/templates/taglibs.jsp" %>
```

Um exemplo de página seria assim:

```xml
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>   

<%@ include file = "WEB-INF/templates/taglibs.jsp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exemplo usando include Estático</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- conteúdo da página -->
 </body>
</html>
```

Você deve observar sempre que um prefixo para *taglib* deve ser declarado apenas uma única vez, então caso inclua o arquivo `taglibs.jsp` em uma página `X` que é incluída em uma página `Y`, não inclua novamente `taglibs.jsp` na página `Y`.

Para caso queira reaproveitar variáveis dinâmicas, no seu caso em que está usando JSTL, basta alterar o escopo da sua variável.

O escopo padrão para `<c:set>` é `page` (veja seção `2.2.1` da [especificação](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jstl-1.2-mrel2-oth-JSpec/)), então a variável não "sobrevive" em outra página quando você faz a inclusão.

Então, para alterar isto, basta usar algo assim:

```xml
<c:set var="sala" value="${listaSala.getSala(usuarioLogado.sala.id)}" scope="request" />
<c:set var="usuarioLogado" value="${validaLogin.testaLoginProfessor(pageContext.request)}" scope="request" />
```

Comment: hum, então eu acho que é isso. No php faço include de 3 páginas em 1 arquivo e o código da primeira incluída esta disponível para a segunda incluída. No caso, então, ao invés de usar  <jsp:include page=", devo usar então <%@ include file=" da jstl que é a que faz o mesmo que o include do php

Comment: Bom, vamos la. Coloquei da forma abaixo em um arquivo prefixo.jsp.:

<jsp:useBean id="constantes" class="util.Constantes" />
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="u" uri="/WEB-INF/myutils.tld" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

Mas mesmo assim, as <c:set scope="request" não estão encontrando as tablib

Comment: @CarlosRocha acho que não entendeu a resposta, talvez não seja uma única dúvida também... Na resposta lhe dou um exemplo completo do que deve conter o arquivo e você incluiu coisas diferente. Veja [isto](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagx.html) e entenda antes o ciclo de vida das coisas em JSP.

Comment: Olha só. Criei um arquivo jsp e coloquei nele 2 linhas apenas 

<%@ include file = "../_global/prefixos.jsp" %> e 
<%@ include file="../_global/testaAdmin.jsp"  %>. 

em prefixo.jsp coloquei a 

<%@ taglib prefix="c"    uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

Na testa admin coloquei 

<c:set var="usuarioLogado" value="${validaLogin.testaLoginProfessor(pageContext.request)}" scope="request" />

Mas não funciona. Dá aviso de atenção!

Comment: @CarlosRocha leia a resposta novamente e veja quando usar um ou outro include, conforme dito, você tem que saber quando é para uso estático ou para uso dinâmico. Por fim, estude o link que inclui no comentário anterior. Obrigado.

Comment: Li novamente e a única coisa que vi de diferente é que você usou EL na chamada ao arquvo:  ${nomeDoArquivo.ext}. Mas assim não dá. E sem o  outro arquivo interno não reconhecem a tablib!

Comment: Alterei a pergunta com as mudanças propostas!

Comment: @CarlosRocha bom, este é meu último comentário sobre esta questão: 1. você já tentou fazer inclusão de `prefixos.jsp` em `testaProfessor.jsp` e não na página final, que não usa o prefixo `c`?; 2. não uso EL, e sim uma propriedade qualquer, isto é um exemplo. Bons estudos.

Comment: Não tentei pois não é apenas testaProfessor.jsp que usará as taglibs mas principalmente a página perguntaConteudo.jsp usará. Se for preciso adicionar a taglib na perguntaConteudo.jsp também então ficará igual ao <jsp include. O que você acha?

Comment: @CarlosRocha infelizmente eu não sei como esta o seu projeto, e nem pretendo olhar. Eu vou insistir novamente e pedir que você entenda como a comunidade funciona. Esta resposta é uma possível solução, podendo ser usada em *N* diferentes projetos. A forma que você usará no seu é por sua conta, você tem que saber como usar a solução no seu projeto da forma que ficar melhor. Você ainda está confundindo os includes, o que significa que não entendeu a diferença deles. Leia a especificação, é a última coisa que posso lhe falar, leia e entenda/aprenda como as coisas funcionam.

Comment: Ok, simplifiquei ainda mais a pergunta para ver se entende a minha dúvida. Pois só assim você conseguirá dar uma resposta adequada!